# How to pass variable from Controller to Nova Recource?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I want to pass `$defaultFrom` from **`NewsletterController.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\NewsletterMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class NewsletterController extends Controller
{
    public function send()
    {
        $defaultFrom = 'newsletter@stuttard.de';

        DB::table('newsletter_mails')->insert(['from' => $defaultFrom]);


        $emails = DB::select('select * from newsletters order by id desc');

        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            Mail::to($email)->send(new NewsletterMail());
        }
    }
}
```

to **`NewsletterMail.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;

class NewsletterMail extends Resource
{
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),

            Text::make('From', 'from')->default($defaultFrom)->placeholder($defaultFrom),
        ];
    }
}
```

I've tried to put `public $defaultFrom;` above the `fields()` function or call `new NewsletterMail($defaultFrom)` but this seems to be wrong syntax. Sorry, I'm a bit new to Laravel.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You cannot do that. Also, why are you using a raw SELECT ? Use the models... `Newsletter::all()` instead of `select`... (it should be `get()` with a limit...)...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have `Newsletter` model. Move `$defaultFrom` to model as `public const DEFAULT_FROM = 'newsletter@stuttard.de';`. After doing this, you can call it's value in both places using `Newsletter::DEFAULT_FROM`.